# IP Address Details

Tags: java, ip, whois, amazon-mobile-ads

We're platform which required to find out the details of person's IP address and then cook up details based on that.

For that we need information of Connection Type (Cellular / Wireless / Cable / dsl / diaup) from IP address.

We already use maxmind service to find out. but they are not providing suffient information for 30% of ip's.

Example: 165.209.118.20
https://db-ip.com/165.209.118.20

Anyone can on same platform already? help me here!!

Answer (score 0):

The information you are trying to get cant be retrieved from the IP address, all you can find out from the ip address is the ISP, geographic region, and reverse dns, connection type is not detectable from IP, you may be able to evaluate it based on bandwidth but this would have to be tested from the client side.

Comment: But how these few these(maxmind, db-ip.com, ip2location, etc.,) people able to provide such information.?

do we have any other way / providers to find out ?

Comment: The ISP that owns the IP address is easily verified using standard DNS infrastructure, these services use whois services and a caching database to store the data and provide easy access to it, as for the other data such as connection type and speed, this can't be trusted as true and correct as it is based on data they have sourced from other locations such as people filling out what type of connection they are on. Additionally most ISP's around the world assign dynamic IP addresses to customers using DHCP and so the connection type can change from one day to the next based on who has the IP.

Comment: @sathish The whois output for the IP blocks can provide some heuristics, but there are only heuristics, same for name. See the `descr` field in RIR whois, and for example some hostnames may have `adsl` or `dhcp` in their string which may *hint* towards some kind of specific access. But otherwise, in short, your task is impossible to reach for 100% of cases.